# Typing a comment block and 5o *[ESC] creates extra spaces

Tags: vim, editor

I am learning vim and in the process learned that you can tell a command to automatically repeat itself. So this has some application in adding lines to a comment block in C code quickly. 
So I would type

```
    \
    60a*[ESC]
    5o *[ESC]
```

etc to complete the block, but the command

```
    5o *[ESC]
```

produces

```
    *
     *
      *
       *
        *
```

which doesn't seem like it is following what the command is supposed to do? Any insight as to why this would happen?

Note: If I do it without the space the behavior is as expected (a vertical line of *'s), but that space is pretty necessary to not waste some time.

SOLVED: o puts a new line directly under your cursor.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem, and am marking it solved

'o' creates a new line UNDER your cursor